# TypeError: Wrong number of dimensions: expected 0, got 1 with shape (6,)

Tags: python, pymc3

I am performing a linear regression analysis using bayessian method.

```
X = data.drop(columns='Power')
Y = data['Power']
a_0=1.
b_0=1.
mu_0=(0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.)
row1=[1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]
row2=[0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.]
row3=[0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.]
row4=[0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.]
row5=[0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.]
row6=[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.]

Sigma_0 =np.array([row1,row2,row3,row4,row5,row6])
with pm.Model() as model:
sigma_square = 1.0 / pm.Gamma('sigma square', alpha=a_0, beta=b_0)

w = pm.MvNormal("w", mu=mu_0, cov=Sigma_0)
likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu=np.dot(X,w), cov=sigma_square + np.dot(X.T ,np.dot(Sigma_n, X)), observed=Y)
trace = sample(3000, return_inferencedata=True)
```

This returns the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in ()
2     sigma_square = 1.0 / pm.Gamma('sigma square', alpha=a_0, beta=b_0)
3
----> 4     w = pm.MvNormal("w", mu=mu_0, cov=Sigma_0)
5     likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu=np.dot(X,w), cov=sigma_square + np.dot(X.T ,np.dot(Sigma_n, X)), observed=Y)
6     trace = sample(3000, return_inferencedata=True)

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymc3/distributions/distribution.py in __new__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs)
120         else:
121             dist = cls.dist(*args, **kwargs)
```

--> 122         return model.Var(name, dist, data, total_size, dims=dims)
123
124     def **getnewargs**(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymc3/model.py in Var(self, name, dist, data, total_size, dims)
1136             if getattr(dist, "transform", None) is None:
1137                 with self:
-> 1138                     var = FreeRV(name=name, distribution=dist, total_size=total_size, model=self)
1139                 self.free_RVs.append(var)
1140             else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymc3/model.py in **init**(self, type, owner, index, name, distribution, total_size, model)
1667             self.distribution = distribution
1668             self.tag.test_value = (
-> 1669                 np.ones(distribution.shape, distribution.dtype) * distribution.default()
1670             )
1671             self.logp_elemwiset = distribution.logp(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/graph/utils.py in **setattr**(self, attr, obj)
264
265         if getattr(self, "attr", None) == attr:
--> 266             obj = self.attr_filter(obj)
267
268         return object.**setattr**(self, attr, obj)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/type.py in filter(self, data, strict, allow_downcast)
180         if self.ndim != data.ndim:
181             raise TypeError(
--> 182                 f"Wrong number of dimensions: expected {self.ndim},"
183                 f" got {data.ndim} with shape {data.shape}."
184             )

TypeError: Wrong number of dimensions: expected 0, got 1 with shape (6,).

It seems my covariance matrix does not meet the required type\format. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Please revise your post so that it contains a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and does *not* contain [images of code or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please add that in the form of an edit to your original post.

Comment: Instead of NumPy, try using [`theano.tensor` linear algebra operations](https://theano-pymc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/tensor/basic.html#linear-algebra).